# jQuery append hrefs to mulitple words in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, append

I have a div with a class name (.product) and what i want to do is find multiple different words and for each word append/replace them with a href link or span etc.

There would be multiple different words to append to so it would most likely be a foreach run.

I have tried the code below but just cant get it to stick as its only replacing the whole last word variable in the script.

```
jQuery('.product').each(function(){
var word1 = jQuery(this).text().replace(/word1/g,"<span>word1</span>");
jQuery(this).html(word1);
});

jQuery('.product').each(function(){
var word2 = jQuery(this).text().replace(/word2/g,"<span>word1</span>");
jQuery(this).html(word2);
});
```

If this is not possible with jQuery/JS, what about php, how would I scan through a database text area value/content and replace foreach variable(word) and replace with href link?

Any help would be appreciated.

cheers

Comment: can you share the html.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and desired output?

Comment: Lets say I have a div like so...<div class="product">test Ipsum rule britannia lorem fish and chips ipsum going to the loo cheers mate crumpets mate off to the pub good day John harry potter cup of tea cup of tea crumpets. </div> and i want to find the words test, harry..etc and append links to each of them, but these links would be different for each found word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt looks good, it is just missing one bit.  Rather than changing the `text` and pushing it into the HTML, try changing the text in the HTML and pushing the HTML back ... and put correct html in (`</span>`) ...

```
jQuery('.product').each(function(){
  var word1 = jQuery(this).html().replace(/word1/g,"<span>word1</span>");
  jQuery(this).html(word1);
});

jQuery('.product').each(function(){
  var word2 = jQuery(this).html().replace(/word2/g,"<span>word1</span>");
  jQuery(this).html(word2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're wanting to wrap words with `<span>` tag. You can do the below using `html` with function overload and replacing words with regex. `$0` means the matched word.

```
jQuery('.product').each(function() {
   $(this).html(function() {
      return $(this).text().replace(/\w+/g, "<span>$0</span>");
   });
});
```